# Update a content type field's allowed values programmatically

Tags: 8, entities

I have a list field in the content type and in the `config` table , the field storage details saved as follows :

```
collection:
name: field.storage.node.field_ip_range_sec_zone
data: a:17:{s:4:"uuid";s:36:"9d20e561-e39c-4c11-b100-ff3a29a75267";s:8:"langcode";
                                            s:2:"en";s:6:"status";b:1;s:12:"dependencies";a:1:{s:6:"module";a:3{i:0;s:17:
                                        "field_permissions";i:1;s:4:"node";i:2;s:7:"options";}}s:20:"third_party_settings";
                                    a:1:{s:17:"field_permissions";a:1:{s:15:"permission_type";s:6:"public";}}s:2:"id";
                                s:28:"node.field_ip_range_sec_zone";s:10:"field_name";s:23:"field_ip_range_sec_zone";
                            s:11:"entity_type";s:4:"node";s:4:"type";s:11:"list_string";s:8:"settings";a:2:
                        {s:14:"allowed_values";a:3:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"value";s:2:"E1";s:5:"label";s:2:"E1";}
                i:1;a:2{s:5:"value";s:2:"C2";s:5:"label";s:2:"C2";}i:2;a:2{s:5:"value";s:2:"D1";s:5:"label";s:2:"D1";}}
            s:23:"allowed_values_function";s:0:"";}s:6:"module";s:7:"options";s:6:"locked";b:0;s:11:
        "cardinality";i:1;s:12:"translatable";b:1;s:7:"indexes";a:0:{}s:22:"persist_with_no_fields";
    b:0;s:14:"custom_storage";b:0;}
```

As you can see there is Allowed values (**`E1,C2,D1`**) , and now i want to add an additional value to the allowed values , How can i do that ?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

---

I could get the allowed values using the following :

```
$entity_type = 'node';
$bundle = 'ip_range';
$field_name = 'field_ip_range_sec_zone';
$ip_sec_zone_storage_values = \Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig::loadByName($entity_type, $field_name);
```

But dont know how to update it , Any idea ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are settings, you get them using `$ip_sec_zone_storage_values->getSetting('allowed_values')`,, in there you'll find those settings, you can add another one, set the settings back with setSetting('allowed_values', $allowed_values) and then ->save() to save the field storage config:

```
$allowed_values = $ip_sec_zone_storage_values->getSetting('allowed_values');
// The new value.
$allowed_values[$ipseczone] = $ipseczone;
$ip_sec_zone_storage_values->setSetting('allowed_values', $allowed_values);
$ip_sec_zone_storage_values->save();
```

Comment: Not clear on the save part.. Is it **ip_sec_zone_storage_values->setSettings("custom values")** ?

Comment: place it as an answer , i will accept it ,  iused it like : **$allowed_values = $ip_sec_zone_storage_values->getSetting('allowed_values'); $allowed_values[$ipseczone] = $ipseczone;//the new value i want to add
        $ip_sec_zone_storage_values->setSetting('allowed_values', $allowed_values); 
        $ip_sec_zone_storage_values->save();**

Answer (score 0):

After many hours i finally found solution. I dynamically created options for multi select field and got error message on submit that choosen select in wrong option.

It requires add new options to allowed_values for that field. 
Here is the solution:

```
 //load your field
 $field_purchasers = \Drupal\field\EntityFieldStorageConfig::loadByName('user', 'field_purchaseres');
 //subscribe new options to this field
$field_purchasers->setSetting('allowed_values_function','module_name_allowed_values_function' );
//save configuration
$field_purchasers->save();
```

In your .module file write in callback function :

```
function module_name_allowed_values_function(FieldStorageConfig $definition, ContentEntityInterface $entity = NULL, $cacheable) {
  $options = [
    1 => 'My new option 1',
    2 => 'My new option 2',
    3 => 'My new option 3',
   ];
  return $options;
}
```